# Replace 2 successive lines using sed

Tags: sed

I've been trying to replace successive lines with the following `sed` commands :

```
sed -i -e '/string1/{N;s/string2/string2_replaced/;N;s/string3/string3_replaced}' file1

sed -i -e '/string1/{n;s/string2/string2_replaced/;n;s/string3/string3_replaced}' file1
```

where file1 contains:

```
string1
string2
string3
```

I keep getting `sed: unmatched '/'`. How can I change the contents of file1 to:

```
string1
string2_replaced
string3_replaced
```

so that string2 and string3 are replaced only if they are on successive lines and if they are immediately after a line that matches string1?

Also, how can I search and replace string2 if I am not sure where (which line) exactly it occurs, but sure that it occurs after string1?

Comment: You missed the last `/`, it's `s/string3/string3_replaced/`. Also not all sed implementations support multiple commands in the same line within `{` and `}`.

Comment: This isn't complicated. You just pull in the next two lines (with `N;N`) if the line matches `string1` and then check if the pattern space matches `string1` followed by a newline followed by `string2` followed by another newline and `string3` (newline is `\n`). If so, you do the substitutions. You think you can do it by yourself ?

Comment: I did that. :)
Now, I would like to know a way to replace string2 when I don't know where exactly it comes (say maybe a few lines later) after string1.

Comment: Good :) If you managed to do it please post an answer (you'll get upvoted if the answer is correct). I'm not sure I understand your other question: do you want to replace `string2` only if it occurs somewhere in the file after `string1` (but not before it) ?

Comment: That's right. The scenario when I don't know how many lines after `string1` `string2` occurs.

Comment: Post an answer to your question and I'll show you how to do this too... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed the last `/`, it's `s/string3/string3_replaced/`:

```
sed -e '/string1/{N;s/string2/string2_replaced/;N;s/string3/string3_replaced/}' file1
```

Note that not all `sed` implementations support multiple commands in the same line within `{` and `}`. For portability:

```
sed -e '/string1/ {
  N
  s/string2/string2_replaced/
  N
  s/string3/string3_replaced/
}' file1
```

Comment: it seems something like `s/^(.*):.*$/\1: false` doesn't work in `{N;/s/<STRING>/<STRING>/;}` format, am I right?. ie: convert `xxx: true` to `xxx: false` by `sed -e '/string1/ {n;s/^([^:]+):.*$/\1: false/;}' file`.